# Adding a calendar via script to yahoo calendar

Tags: calendar, yahoo

I have a calendar link, "http://www.lalindyhop.com/calendar_script.php"

And I want to add the events on this link to my yahoo calendar.

Do I have to ask for some other link, or I can use this one somehow to add it to my calendar.

Thanks
Zeeshan

Comment: hi did u find any solution to this?? please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your calendar link seems to have disappeared. In any case here are some links that may help:

[Adding Events to Users Calendars – Part 2 – Web Calendars](http://richmarr.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/adding-events-to-users-calendars-part-2-web-calendars/)

[Adding Calendar Events to Yahoo](http://armcnallie.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/adding-calendar-events-to-yahoo/)

[Yahoo! Calendar "Add Event" Seed URL Parameters](http://chris.photobooks.com/tests/calendar/Notes.html)